# Scratchcard PHP script

Tags: php, random, numbers

I'm working on a scratchcard script and I was wondering if someone could help me out, if you don't understand odds this may melt your brain a little!

So, the odds can vary: `1/$x;` Let's say for now: `$x = 36;`

So here's what I am trying to understand...

- I want to generate `9` random numbers between `1 and 5`.
- I want the odds of `3` numbers matching equivalent to `1/36`.
- It must be impossible to generate over 3 duplicate numbers at a time.

I can imagine an array loop of some kind would probably be the correct way of passage?

Comment: try to only ask one question per post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes - and this is one of those times - cheating is the best way to do what you want to do.

```
a) Set up an array of your 9 numbers, and a 2nd frequency array (5 elements) that counts which number occurs how often.
b) Generate a random number 1-5. Set the 1st and 2nd card to this number, and mark this number with 2 in your freqency array.
c) If random(36) < 1 (1/36 probability), set your 3rd card to the same number and mark this number with 3 in your frequency array.
d) Generate the rest of the cards - find a random number, repeat while frequency of the found number >=2, set the next card to number, increase frequency of the found number.
e) When finished, shuffle the cards (generate 2 random numbers between 1 and 9, swap the 2 cards, repeat 20-30 times).
```

Part d) is what i call cheating - you've put your 1/36 probabilty in step c), and in d) you just make sure you don't generate another match. e) is used to hide that from the user.